# Why aren't there more Ash-Red pigeons?

Tags: genetics, zoology, population-genetics

My favorite color pigeon is Ash-Red, but I don't see a lot of them.  I figured it must be a recessive phenotype, but when I googled it, I found out it's dominant.  So why aren't there more Ash-Red pigeons around?

Edit: I'm in North America.

Edit 2: [This](http://learn.genetics.utah.edu/content/pigeons/color/) website from the University of Utah is where I learned that Ash-Red is the dominant phenotype.

Comment: "I don't see a lot of them" is a bit of a vague statement. Have you checked whether there is some data available that shows that population levels for Ash-red pigeons are low in North America? It could simply be that the pigeons are more timid than other species or that the particular micro-enviorment you live in (it's an assumption here) is not suitable for Ash-red pigeons.

Comment: Good point!  Searching for specific numbers of Ash-Red pigeons in North America actually helped me find a book with a really good answer to my question... thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Biology.SE

**Assumption**

I will assume it is true that the allele causing a ash-red plumage is dominant over all other alleles. Note however that you should cite your reference when making such claim in your post.

**Dominance and allele frequency**

Phenotypes associated to a dominant allele `A` aren't necessarily more common than the phenotype of the recessive allele `a`. It all depends on the allele frequency. If the dominant allele is at low frequency then both `AA` and `Aa` (both displaying the dominant phenotype) are at low frequency (esp. `AA` individuals) and most individuals are `aa` and show the recessive phenotype.

**Learn more**

You might want to read about Hardy-Weinberg rule [with this post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58205/solving-hardy-weinberg-problems) for example.