# Reducing the Proportion of Phenotype in Hardy Weinberg Population through Selection

Tags: natural-selection, hardy-weinberg

I was given the following question:

*You travel to an unknown island and find a population of strangely colored
slugs! Upon close investigation, you notice that 16% of the slugs have a
shriveled tails, a most terrible condition you decide to name Yilunemia. The condition makes the affected slugs have a 50% chance of surviving to
reproduce. This is a autonomic recessive condition caused by a single gene,
and heterozygotes are not affected.*

*Assuming Yilunemia confers no discernible evolutionary advantage, how
many generations should it take for the proportion of slugs with the Yilunemia disease to fall below 5%?*

Possible answers:

- 5
- 6
- 7
- 8
- 9

I've tried to apply usual formula for frequency after selection:

*0.36 + 0.48 + 0.16 = 1*

*0.36 + 0.48 + 0.5 * 0.16 = 0.92*

Divide by 0.92 gives:

*0.39 + 0.52 + 0.087 = 1*

If I keep doing this, after the 3rd generation, the frequency of Yilunemia condition is 0.045, which is less than 5%. However, this isn't an answer choice, therefore I must be doing something wrong.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The theory**

You have to use the diploid selection equation (see [here](http://www.zoology.ubc.ca/~bio336/Bio336/Simulations/DiploidSelection/GeneticModel.html)). Let $p$ be the the frequency of the recessive allele of interest, you get

$$p' = \frac{p^2 W_{aa} + p(1-p)W_{aA}}{\bar W}$$

, where

$$\bar W = p^2 W_{aa} + 2p(1-p)W_{aA} + (1-p)^2W_{AA}$$

You can simply iterate over with this equation. Do no forget to recompute $\bar W$ at each generation as the allele frequency changes, so does the mean fitness $\bar W$. Also, do not forget that we are looking for the generation where the frequency of sick individuals is lower than $0.05$, that is the generation where $p<\sqrt{0.05}$.

I don't think this recursion equation has any general solution unfortunately. This would mean that iteration is the only way to got.

**The practice**

I am a bit too lazy to compute everything by hand so here a short R code that will do the calculations for us.

```
frequencySickIndividuals = 0.16
p = sqrt(frequencyHomozygoteRecessiveMutants)
waa = 0.5
waA = 1
wAA = 1
for (generation in 0:10)
{
    frequencySickIndividuals = p^2
    cat(paste0("Generation ", generation, " frequency sick individuals = ", frequencySickIndividuals, "\n"))
    p = (p^2 * waa + p*(1-p)*waA) / (p^2*waa + 2*p*(1-p)*waA + (1-p)^2*wAA)
}
```

It outputs

```
Generation 0 frequency sick individuals = 0.16
Generation 1 frequency sick individuals = 0.120982986767486
Generation 2 frequency sick individuals = 0.0935350533786218
Generation 3 frequency sick individuals = 0.0738632061510922
Generation 4 frequency sick individuals = 0.0594638505565122
Generation 5 frequency sick individuals = 0.0487003101360286
Generation 6 frequency sick individuals = 0.0404940467744661
Generation 7 frequency sick individuals = 0.034123112395776
Generation 8 frequency sick individuals = 0.0290951856295452
Generation 9 frequency sick individuals = 0.0250680151553009
Generation 10 frequency sick individuals = 0.0217991643532054
```

So, it actually takes 5 generations to reach an allele frequency lower than $\sqrt{0.05}$.

**Source of information on hardy-Weinberg problems**

Note by the way, you might be interested in having a look at a tutorial on how to solve Hardy-Weinberg problems on the post [Solving Hardy Weinberg problems](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58205/solving-hardy-weinberg-problems).

Comment: I understand how to do it this way. I was thinking, given that I have no shouldn't take more than 1.5 minutes or so to (according to problem guidelines), if this is the fastest way to solving the problem.

Comment: Please see edit.