# How to solve these kinds of problems?

Tags: population-genetics

16% of people in a population can not roll their tongue .what is the frequency of people which are heterozygous of this character? Please ,any one help and guide me to solve these kind of problems. 
 I tried to solve it using punnet square but i failed . [image]

So i tried my best please help me to solve this.

Comment: Homework questions are off-topic on Biology unless you have shown your attempt at an answer. For more information see our [homework policy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework).

Comment: @David  He show some attempt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solving Hardy Weinberg problems](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58205/solving-hardy-weinberg-problems)

Comment: Hint: The very first step is to define which genotype can not roll their tongue. Then, you know that 16% of the population have these genotypes. From this, you can find out the frequency of heterozygote in the population thanks to Hardy-Weinberg. For more information, please look at the post marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I definitely recommend looking at your calculations. The "unable to roll tongue" trait is recessive, not dominant. Look at the Hardy-Weinberg equation $p^2 + 2pq + q^2 = 1$. Try to extract the root of $q^2$ and you will get the right solution.

Comment: https://www.nature.com/scitable/definition/hardy-weinberg-equation-299 this might help you too.