# Can you find the amount of heterozygotes in a pop. from the phenotypes shown in the pop

Tags: evolution

I know the hardy Weinberg equation but that is for the amount of alleles not the amount of phenotypes. So if there are 600 black(dominant) organisms in the population and 400 green(recessive) organisms. Can you figure out how many of the blacks are actually heterozygous?

Comment: No one want to do your homework for you.  You will get far better answer if you show what you think the answer is and why.

Comment: In short, you would need to know the genetic architecture underlying your trait. How many loci? How does each allele contribute? In your question, you seem to assume that there is a single bi-allelic locus with a simple dominance relationship (where black is dominant). Then yes, you can. What have you tried? You will find the answer in the post [Solving Hardy Weinberg problems](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58205/solving-hardy-weinberg-problems)

Comment: Number, not amount. If you need help with your English you may find the following example useful: “amount of sugar, but number of lumps. This is not pedantry — in science precision of expression matters.